# What does 8 root 2.5 ($\sqrt[8]{2.5}$) mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

$8$ root of $2.5$?

I have calculated the equation and found $12.6$ is the answer. However, the answer given is $1.12$

so what could I have done wrong? Thanks

Comment: It seems you misinterpreted $\sqrt[8]{2.5}$ as $8\sqrt{2.5}$.

Comment: It means that if you multiply this number by itself $8$ times then you will get $2.5$, in formulas: $x = \sqrt[8]{2.5} \implies x^8 = 2.5$

Answer (score 2):

The $8^{th}$ root of $2.5$ is expressed as $\sqrt[8]{2.5}$ or $2.5^{\frac18}$, which is approximately $1.12$.